# I need to send a download request from server 1 to server 2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a programming code in Python language, and I need to send a download request from server 1 to server 2, wait for the download to be completed, and then server 2 return the request to server 1, and all this is in Python language

I want to have something like this

## Server - 1

```
import fs
sf = fs.open_fs("sftp://Username:Pass@ip:port")
sf.runThePythonFile("/home/Downloader.py")
        ## Wait for it to complete and then keep working
print("Done")
```

## Server - 2

```
import sys
import time
import os

def DownloadTheFile(url):
   ## Donwload Fun
   _bool = True
   return _bool
```

As for the download script, it works fine, the only thing I want is communication between the two servers

*Any suggestions?*

Comment: Not much usefull people can say about this. Communication between 2 servers can be done in many ways and what the best one will be depends on your usecases. Most low-level but functional will be sockets. More high level but pretty flexible will most likely be Rest. More convoluted could be to use a message queue in between. Might be a good idea to check them and see what fits your needs more. Otherwise, just google.

Comment: Well, thank you, I'll keep searching anyway